# NSInternalInconsistencyException occurs when insertng indexPath into tableView but only when row count gets above a certain threshold

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two tables in which I am dragging and dropping between them: sourceTableView and targetTableView. They each have their own tableViewController. A parentContainerViewController manages a 'slide out' UI which allows the user to 'longPressGesture' on the sourceTableView cell which causes sourceTableView to slide out exposing the targetTableView below at which time the user can 'drop' the dragged cell into place within the targetTableView.  All works well as it should until the targetTableView grows to about 21-27 rows in size.  Once we get to this size and if I re-run the project I start to get the NSInternalInconsistencyException. The detail of the error reads: reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (27) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

At first I thought I was getting a race condition issue since the number of rows before the update is "0" and after it is "27".  Maybe the tableView wasn't able to load before the user drags in the item and calls the insertIndex method on tableView.  But then I noticed that it works fine until we get to a certain length.  Race condition wouldn't make sense in this case.  Now I am thinking it has something to do with with 'visible cell' loaded vs not loaded.  But why would it be '0' rows?  I have looked all over for the answer.  There are many NSInconsistency but none that seem to answer my specific problem.

This is the function call to tell targetTableViewController to insert an item into its datasource then tells targetTableView to insertRowsAtIndexPath :

```
  dragDropDataSource.tableView(self, insertDataItem: item, atIndexPath: indexPath)

  self.beginUpdates()

  self.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)


  self.endUpdates()
```

Here is the targetTableViewController code implementing the above call:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, insertDataItem dataItem : AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void {

    if let di = dataItem as? DataItem {
      data.insert(di, atIndex: indexPath.row)
    }
```

data is the array that stores the 'DataItems' which are shown in the tableView rows.

Additionally.  The targetTableView is initialized with data via a call in its viewDidLoad() to  getMyTopTen()

```
    func getMyTopTen() {

        let pwAPI = PowWowAPI()
        pwAPI.getMyTopTen(self.boardId!) {
          (entries:[Entry])in

      for(var i=0; i < entries.count; i++) {
        let dataItem = DataItem(indexes: String(i), entry: entries[i])
        self.data.append(dataItem)
      }

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.targetTableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

I hope I have explained the problem sufficiently. If not please help me make this question better.  I am new to asking questions here.

Comment: can you change the cell animation Fade to None 'and check it.. I thing, your code may try to insert a cell during the tableview reloading process

Comment: Tried that.  self.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None) Now I am getting an assertion related to animations in addition to the NSInconsitencyException. *** Assertion failure in -[PowWow.DragAndDropTableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720

Comment: Is there a way I can delay the insertion until after reload?  Or ensure the tableView is loaded.  I thought beginUpdates was supposed to do something like this.

Comment: Correction:  I am getting that Animation related assertion despite the value being fade or none.  Could this be a root cause?  I hadn't noticed the assertion before.

Comment: I found this post online which seems to explain my exact issue only instead of rows they are having issues with sections.  I don't understand how to implement their fix.  http://www.seifeet.com/2014/03/ios-custom-data-source-race-condition.html

Comment: Did you override this method in your code?
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

Comment: You can use two different NSMutableArray instance one for storing dataItems temporary and other for tableview datasource..(tableview datasource instance is mutable copy instance of stored dataItems temporary )